# do while loop does only execute scanf_s(" %d", &variable); once

Tags: c, scanf, do-while, c11

When running into the do while loop my I'm only asked for input once and run into an endless loop afterwards. Does someone know why?

```
do {
        printf("Insert the year published: \n");
        scanf_s(" %d", &yearPublished);
        if (1 < yearPublished && yearPublished <= currentYear) {
            newMovie->yearPublished = yearPublished;
            wrongInput = false;
            printf("Correct input"); //DEBUG
        } else {
            printf("Please enter a valid integer number!\n");
            wrongInput = true;
        }
} while(wrongInput);
```

Comment: You should always check return value of `scanf` and similar functions

Comment: Side note: you don't need the `wrongInput` variable, just `break` when you get a valid input.

Comment: What is your input? What is the exact output? Do you test valid or invalid input? That loop doesn't create an endless loop without output. The problem is likely to be in the part you do not show. Please read [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. And copy-paste (as text) the input you use as well as the output.

Comment: On a different note, there's no need for the leading space in the format string. Leading space is to skip over any leading white-space, but the `%d` format already have it built-in.

Comment: And a ***guess*** about your problem: You give some non-integer input. That causes `scanf_s` to fail, but not remove the invalid input from the buffer. So the next iteration it will attempt to read the very same input again. Read a *string* using `fgets` and use `sscanf` to attempt to parse the input. And rememeber to check what `sscanf_s` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution for the problem which is caused from not clearing the input buffer:

with adding the following at the end of the while loop this can be fixed

```
// Clear the input buffer
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```